# get the values mentioned in reference column

Tags: sql

I want to join two tables(Table1,Table2) which should return the status of the references mentioned in table1 reference column(12,14,18,19). Table2 has information of the ID which are mapped to the reference in individual rows as shown below.

Table1:

Datatype of columns are:  ID is of type integer,Name is character varying,reference is character varying,status is character varying.

```
ID  Name    reference  status
10  PAX11   12,14,18   Undelivered
11  PAX193             Undelivered
12  ASD1               delivered
14  PAA                delivered
90  PQA     19         Undelivered
18  PX                 Halt
19  ONA                delivered
```

Table2:
Below 3 columns are of integer type.

```
sno  ID   reference
1    4    100
2    10   12
3    10   14
4    10   18
5    90   19
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: You should really turn reference into a table of it's own then have Table1 and Table2 reference that table through many-to-many tables...

Comment: Can you pls show an example? Is it not possible with the two tables mentioned above? @JohnCullen

Comment: Select status from table1 inner join table2 on (table1.id = table2.id) have you tried this?

Comment: Somebody else answered it - you need to have a relational database... research that. It's one of the more core concepts of data structures in SQL. You don't want reference to be "12,14,18"... you want another table to hold ID and reference... like [**[ID, reference]**, [10, 12], [10,14], [10, 18], [90, 19]]... then a separate table entirely to hold... [**reference**, 12, 14, 18, 19, 100] where the first table _references_ the second.

Comment: @JohnCullen - I have Table2 which holds ID and reference. So you mean i need 3 tables to do this?

Comment: If you are binding ID and reference in Table2, why does Table1 have both of those fields?

Comment: If you notice Table1 ID column for value 10 references are 12,14,18 which are again mentioned in ID column of Table1 and for ID 90 reference is 19 which is again mentioned in Table1 ID column.Now i want the status of those references mentioned in Table1 reference column which again is mentioned in the same Table.@JohnCullen

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Also: what is the expected output based on that sample data?

Answer (score 2):

Your data model is wrong. You should put your effort into fixing it. The correct fix is to have *another* table, with one row per `id` and per `sno`. This is called a junction or association table.

What is wrong with the data model? The issue is the `reference` column. Let me count the ways:

- A column should contain a single value, not multiple values.
- The data type should be correct for a value, so a number should not be stored in a character column.
- Foreign keys should be properly defined. You cannot do that with a string list.
- Relational databases have relatively weak string processing capabilities.
- Queries that use `reference` cannot make use of indexing, and statistics might be misleading.
- Relational databases have these great constructs for storing lists.  They are called *tables*, not *strings*.

Comment: Please see Table2,it has ID mapped to single reference. In Table1 for ID 10 we have 12,14,18 references. Whereas Table2 i have mapped ID to a reference with individual value.

Comment: @nan, the point isn't table 2, it's table1. You have three values stored in one column of the first row shown. That violates first normal form for a relational database and is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I agree, as it is the main table which we are storing all the values initially so the reference column in table1 we are storing as character varying which holds multiples IDs(12,14,18) and in Table2 the reference column is of type integer which holds only single value each time. There should be some way by joining those two tables to get the status of 12,14,18 which are mentioned in Table1 itself.@EricBrandt

Comment: @nan . . . Storing the same information in two different tables in competing formats is not recommended.